# How do I use a spacetime diagram for the twin paradox when signals are sent every 24 hours over a 13 year period?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, spacetime

I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around spacetime diagrams. I'm working with the twin paradox, the one leaving the earth is traveling at ${3\over 5}c$, and goes 4 light years away. I calculated that the total time it takes for the spaceship twin is 13.4 years, while the earth twin says it takes 16.75 years. Every spacetime diagram I have seen has the axes the same as below. In that picture there is a signal sent every year, but I have a problem where I need to make a diagram for a signal sent every 24 hours. In order to replicate this I would have to change the perpendicular axis to be in increments of 24 hours, rather than one year. But that seems impossible, I don't have a piece of paper big enough to make that diagram.

However, my professor said to do this problem using a diagram, but it seems to me like it would be more work than doing signal received times by hand. How can I make use of a spacetime diagram when signals are sent frequently?

[image]

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use a resolution of 1 day compared to 1 year for the diagram to be drawn? (It's not just a problem of changing units?) If you really had to draw this detailed with a factor of 365 or so, you could do it with software (like GeoGebra or Desmos) that would let you zoom in to various points of interest. Clearly, the diagram you displayed was computer generated.